# Why does the bot send the same message many times after the bot is hosted by Heroku?

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, google-sheets-api, discord.js

I just set up a bot discord that sends a message to a user on the day of a Spreedsheet event, at 12h and th day before, at 18h ([the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XvIKkYkeKH8mWrUv97w2u-kczoYnWGYl1Mkh1usc0eE/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XvIKkYkeKH8mWrUv97w2u-kczoYnWGYl1Mkh1usc0eE/edit?usp=sharing)). When I run it locally, there is no problem. Then I tried to put it on github, then on heroku, as explained on https://medium.com/@mason.spr/hosting-a-discord-js-bot-for-free-using-heroku-564c3da2d23f . The first 2 embed works, but from the 3rd, it sends the message 3 or 4 times! I guess it's because of the reaction time between the different platforms, but how to solve this problem?

Here is my code https://github.com/D33pOnion/bot.js/blob/master/bot.js, it is long, so I specify that the problem starts at line 144

I expect each embed will only be sent once, after each reaction. Locally, it works very well, but as soon as it is put in place on Heroku, it repeats, from the 3rd embed, several times the same message.

Comment: first thing, use function. Having a 1200 line function **isn't** a good idea. You may know it, but it's still hard to navigate through it, and anyone trying to read will be lost. Function, well named/used, make the code really easy to read. Second thing, are you sure you're bot doesn't react to itself?

Comment: The purpose of this bot is to write a message, to create a reaction to the message and to wait until the reaction is pushed by a user, to send another message. And this several times. But I do not see why create a function, because there are only functions in the code (but I remember that I am a beginner, so maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: This isn't related to the problem, so I won't argue there, but be aware that some standard fix a limit to the limit of line per function you're writing (25, 50 or others limit). I advice you to search why using functions and understand why it's important

Comment: About your problem, did you try to log anything. To understand what is happening?

Comment: I added this line at the beginning: `client.on("debug", function(info){
    console.log(`debug -> ${info}`);
});` 
and every 30-40seconds, in the log: 
`debug -> [ws] [connection] Sending a heartbeat
debug -> [ws] [connection] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 108ms`. 

I also specify that locally, the bot doesn't repeat the same message several times from the 3rd embed. But the 2 first embed are working very well in both cases, locally or by Heroku / Github

Comment: By log I mean, did you try to look at the different variable involved in the problem to see what value they have and why the third embed would repeat?